# Calling Asynchronous Named Pipes instantiated in dot net from Java

Tags: c#, java, named-pipes, asynccallback

This question is related to an earlier, more general question I asked on Java-C# communication, but I think it's probably specific enough to ask separately (let me know if you think I'm wrong - I haven't marked that one as answered yet and will come back to it once I figure out the solution that works best, this question is a step towards that..).

I'm trying to use named pipes to communicate between C# and Java.  I'm basing my code on the example (pointed out by a responder to my previous question) at-
http://v01ver-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/howto-use-named-pipes-to-communicate.html

The blog example works fine, but because in my own code I want to have a callback occur when my Java program connects to the C# instantiated pipe, I have to use an **Asynchronous** pipe (the example in the blog doesn't do this).  So when instantiating the pipe, my code is-

```
 instructionPipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("InstructionPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 4,PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
 instructionPipe.BeginWaitForConnection(new AsyncCallback(instructionPipeServerConnected), new Object());
```

..And then I write a callback called instructionPipeServerConnected that does the stuff I want on getting a connection.

On the Java side, again following the example in the blog, I set up the pipe on the Java side by writing-

```
    instructionPipeJava=new RandomAccessFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\" + "InstructionPipe","rw");
```

However, if I try to write some test data onto this pipe in Java-

```
   instructionPipeJava.write("This Is Test Text".getBytes());
```

And run the code, then the code stalls and can't get past this line.  If I don't use an asynchronous pipe, then 'instructionPipeJava' will be able to write this text to the pipe just fine.  However I need to use an async pipe to use callbacks on the c# side.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Perhaps the issue is that I am using 'new RandomAccessFile(..)' to create the pipe in Java and there is a more suitable way to do this to connect to an async C# pipe?

Comment: I would use FileOutputStream and FileInputStream.  A pipe is not an random access file.  IMHO I would use a Socket which may be simpler to use.

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried changing the RandomAccessFile to FileOutputStream, but this didn't work (the code stalls on the same line as before).  I'm going to have a look into sockets now, thanks

Comment: PS I was advised to give pipes a try because I'm trying to feed rapidly streaming data to a Java program locally and they are considered more reliable for that.

Comment: AFAIK, pipes are implemented using socket in Windows.  I suspect you won't find that much difference between them.  One reason to use a Socket is that it is two way and you know when the other end is connected and when it disconnects.  You can use Sockets to write at a rate of 100K to 300K writes/reads per second (depending on yous CPU speed)

Comment: I have started to take a look at sockets and have set up something to connect between a client and a server.  However, I would like to generate an event when data is received eg from the server to the client.  Is this possible? - I have set up a question here- (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106957/writing-to-an-asynchronoussocketchannel-and-processing-the-data-in-an-event-base)  I also discovered Peter's post at (http://core-java-performance-examples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/test/java/com/google/code/java/core/socket/AsyncPingTest.java) which seems closely related to this.